# "How to fix recurring error message on computer startup related to Visual Studio Code or Node.js?

Tags: c++, runtime

[The error box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2maJ.png)

I got this error whenever I open my computer and it starts to worrying me. I clicked ignore, retry and it goes away but the next day when I open my computer, it comes back.

My guess was it might be because of visual studio code or nodejs because I started to get the error after I downloaded them. I tred uninstall and reinstalling the node.js and visual studio code but it doesn't work. I watched youtube to fix the error but they don't work either. I am kinda newb when it comes these. :( How can I fix this?

Comment: Except for reformatting your hard drive and reinstalling Windows, you're out of luck. For things like these, trying to fix them by running random keyword searches and trying what some random web site says, rarely works.

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling vulcan, then compact your hard drive, the reinstall vulcan.  Hopefully, the compacting will force vulcan to be installed in a new location on the drive.